# Internal scroll interfers with boostrap carousel

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I have a script for local scrolling (click a link it takes you to another part of the page) on a site that also has the Bootstrap carousel implemented as well.

The internal scrolling script seems to override the carousel scripts and not sure how to fix. I tried leveraging jQuery's :not() method but couldn't get it to work the way I needed it to.

[Site is in development here](http://clients.pbj.me/text100/picofemto-landing/)

### JS

```
$('a[href*=#]:not([href=#])').click(function() {
    if (location.pathname.replace(/^\//,'') === this.pathname.replace(/^\//,'') && location.hostname === this.hostname) {
        var target = $(this.hash);
        target = target.length ? target : $('[name=' + this.hash.slice(1) +']');
        if (target.length) {
            $('html,body').animate({
                scrollTop: target.offset().top
            }, 800);
            return false;
        }
    }
```

Comment: Have you tinkered with your selectors at all? Maybe something like $('a[href*=#]:not([href=#],[href*=#carousel])') ...

Answer (score 0):

Try `:not(a[role="button"]`, as in:

```
$('a[href*=#]:not(a[role="button"])').click(function() {
    if (location.pathname.replace(/^\//,'') === this.pathname.replace(/^\//,'') && location.hostname === this.hostname) {
        var target = $(this.hash);
        target = target.length ? target : $('[name=' + this.hash.slice(1) +']');
        if (target.length) {
            $('html,body').animate({
                scrollTop: target.offset().top
            }, 800);
            return false;
        }
    }
});
```

Comment: Thank you! I attempted something like this before but attached the ":not" portion in the wrong area. Appreciate it!